# AngularJS Minification of .config, .run, .factory, .constant

Tags: javascript, angularjs, minify

I've successfully minified a large angular application, but there is one angular file that is not working when it is included. It happens to be the app.js file.

The strange part is that all the annotations look correct, and most of them look like they wouldn't cause a problem anyway.

But the result of minifying them is a blank screen with no error (presumably ng isn't executed somehow).

The code in app.js has no controllers only .config, .run, .factory, .constant.

I've searched all documentation and still have this question:

- Do constants require annotation to be minified?

If so there is no indication here: 
[https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide?PHPSESSID=cae8e98e7ca559b4605d75c813b358ee](http://here)

Also - Would run and config blocks cause minify to fail in any way that you know?

What should I be looking for as a problem for the minification - blank screen no error behavior?

The code is formatted like this:

```
window.app = angular.module('ds.example', ['a','b','c'])

.constant('_', window._ )

.factory('name', ['a','b','c', function (a,b,c) {

}])

.config(['a','b','c', function (a,b,c) {

}])

.run(['a','b','c', function (a,b,c) {

}])

.config(['a','b','c', function (a,b,c) {

]);
```

Do you see anything there that would cause minification to go blank?

UPDATE: putting annotation around the constant had no effect:

.constant('*', [window.*] )

Comment: Can you have multiple .config sections?

Comment: @mfink multiple config sections are fine, in a fairly larger app you will have many.

Comment: @ClintNash Where are you setting window.whatever? did you try window['whatever'] ? How does your original constant looks like , before minification.

Comment: window._ comes from document.window

Comment: @ClintNash i know what is window :) i am asking the property on the window that you are looking at, where is it being set from

Comment: the multiple config sections are functional. One is used for CORS configuration and the other for stateProvider routing.

Comment: ah, makes sense @PSL looking... It is: window._ = lodash;

Comment: how about wrapping it all in a closure?

Comment: IIFE was a good idea, I see it here(http://toddmotto.com/minimal-angular-module-syntax-approach-using-an-iife/), but unfortunately same result.

Comment: do you need `window.app =` ?, or could you just define `angular.module(`...

Comment: you are correct, it is removable. I'll see if it makes a difference...

Comment: So your actual problem is that `.constant('_', window._ )` does not place lodash into constant, due to minification?

Comment: @PSL you may be right. I am pretty sure I removed that line and it made no difference, but maybe it was a bad test. I'll try again, because it seems to be the most likely suspect.